# What's the difference between import virtual machines types in Hyper-V?

Tags: hyper-v

I was importing a virtual machine to my Hyper-V manager and I got 3 options:

- **Register** the virtual machine in place (use the existing unique ID)
- **Restore** the virtual machine in place (use the existing unique ID)
- **Copy** the virtual machine (create a new unique ID)

What's the difference between the three options?

[image: "Choose Import Type" step in "Import Virtual Machine" wizard]

Comment: I can't add an answer now, but some helpful official documentation is available at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/deploy/export-and-import-virtual-machines#import-types

Answer (score 74, accepted):

**Register:** If you have a virtual machine were you have already put all of the virtual machine files exactly where you want them, and you just need Hyper-V to start using the virtual machine where it is.

**Restore:** If your virtual machine files are stored on a file share / removable drive / etc… and you want Hyper-V to move the files to the appropriate location for you, and then register the virtual machine.

**Copy:** If you have a set of virtual machine files that you want to import multiple times (e.g. you are using them as a template for new virtual machines) this is what you want to choose. This will copy the files to an appropriate location, give the virtual machine a new unique ID, and then register the virtual machine.

Source: [Technet forums: Hyper-V Import Wizard: Choose Import Type?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/68aa2cbc-3386-44f5-aa87-b53c395d4b6c/hyperv-import-wizard-choose-import-type?forum=winserverhyperv)

Comment: What about the case where you have all the files on the right disk, but in another folder?  Will Hyper-V move them to sensible locations, or is it best to just put them there yourself?

Comment: FYI answer source is [this TechNet forum post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/68aa2cbc-3386-44f5-aa87-b53c395d4b6c/hyperv-import-wizard-choose-import-type?forum=winserverhyperv) copy and pasted directly. It's good to attribute your sources.