# What's the difference between import virtual machines types in Hyper-V 2012?

Tags: hyper-v

I was importing a virtual machine to my Hyper-V manager and I got 3 options:

```
Register the virtual machine in place   
Restore the virtual machine in place   
Copy the virtual machine
```

What's the difference between the three options?

Comment: Does it occur to you to - ah - read some documentation and get some basic - ah - knowledge as required by this site before asking questions like this?

Comment: Oh, and that is a double of http://serverfault.com/questions/585663/whats-the-difference-between-import-virtual-machines-types-in-hyper-v asked like yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register: If you have a virtual machine were you have already put all of the virtual machine files exactly where you want them, and you just need Hyper-V to start using the virtual machine where it is.

Restore: If your virtual machine files are stored on a file share / removable drive / etc… and you want Hyper-V to move the files to the appropriate location for you, and then register the virtual machine.

Copy: If you have a set of virtual machine files that you want to import multiple times (e.g. you are using them as a template for new virtual machines) this is what you want to choose. This will copy the files to an appropriate location, give the virtual machine a new unique ID, and then register the virtual machine.